# Is using the increment operator in javascript discouraged?

Tags: javascript

I've seen code like the following in some JS libraries:

```
var i;
for (i = 20; i >= 0; i -= 1) 
{
}
```

I wonder why they would choose to decrement `i` in this fashion. Is there something problematic about using `++` and `--` in javascript?

Comment: I doubt very much that there is a problem with ++ or -- operators. Those operators have been with us for a long time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Douglas Crockford, aka the godfather of JavaScript, discourages the `++`.

> **Confusing Pluses and Minuses**
>
> Be careful to not follow a + with + or ++. This pattern can be
>   confusing. Insert parens between them to make your intention clear.
>
> ```
> total = subtotal + +myInput.value;
> ```
>
> is better written as
>
> ```
> total = subtotal + (+myInput.value);
> ```
>
> so that the + + is not misread as ++.

Personally, the -- or ++ is completely okay in a for loop as its meaning is very clear.  I tend to follow most of Crockford's guidelines though because its generally the basis of JS conventions.

See more [here](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html).

Comment: Using `+` in that way is typically to convert a string to a number. I'd argue that usage in and of itself isn't clear.

Comment: -1: This is not about the "++" operator, but about a single "+", followed by either another "+" or a "++". See your examples.

Comment: The example isn't point on, but they are still referring to the same concept of code that isn't confusing or misleading.  Unfortunately, the only example I know if is a video of a presentation that Crockford gave.  -1 to you sir for now understanding the concept.

Answer (score 5):

The increment and decrement operators work just fine in JavaScript. A lot of people don't use them because Crockford recommends against using them in his book `JavaScript: The Good Parts`. I generally like Crockford but I do feel this particular recommendation is a bit draconian. I've yet to see any convincing situation or evidence that suggests they are harmful.

Comment: +1 - *"I do feel this recommendation is a bit draconian"* ...as are a lot of Crockford's recommendations.

Comment: +1. If you know what they do & how they work then I can't see why there's a problem using them in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed Douglas Crockford discouraged it as a bad feature of the language, most notably in his book "JavaScript: The Good Parts". It can be used in creating easy to miss errors and code harder to reason about.

What I don't see here, and I'll add, is a quote of Douglas Crockford from one of his lectures on JavaScript:

> For example, the ++ operator, this was added for B for doing point
>   arithmetic. We have since determined that point arithmetic is harmful,
>   so we don't do it anymore.  Modern languages do not support point
>   arithmetic.  The last popular language that had point arithmetic was
>   C++.  A language so bad it was named after this operator.  But the
>   operator refused to die.  It's still in all of our languages even
>   though we don't need it to increment pointers anymore.
>
> Now we use it to add one to variables.  Which is completely
>   unnecessary.  But we do it.  Unfortunately it leads to a style of
>   programming in which you try to write one-liners.  In which you try to
>   take a whole bunch of stuff and try to smush it down into one line. 
>   That leads to really bad code.  Stuff which is very hard to maintain,
>   very hard to correct.  We've seen security errors, buffer overruns,
>   those sort of things.  This operator is always implicated in those
>   sorts of security errors.  h
>
> I found in my own practice, any time I use ++ anywhere, this thing
>   takes hold of me.  I can't control it.  It makes me want to take code
>   and try to mush it down to one line.  Even though I know that's a
>   stupid thing to do, I can't control myself.  This things takes hold of
>   me, and I start writing really stupid stuff thinking I'm being really
>   smart.  Eventually I had to stop.  I couldn't do it a little bit.  I
>   had to stop completely.
>
> I said no more ++ from now on.  It's +=1.  I can relax.  It's easy.  I
>   can just write good programs now.  Food tastes better.  Everything's
>   great.  For a while I thought it was just me.  But now I'm
>   recommending everybody +=1 all the time every time.  +=1 it's great. 
>   So much better.
>
> I hear from people all the time saying I want to be able to write x++
>   cause it means the same thing, instead of having to go...  (mimics
>   typing few keystrokes) I can't go...  (mimics typing few less
>   keystrokes) I don't have that kind of time!  **Except that the typing
>   time is irrelevant.  It is completely irrelevant.  We don't spend our
>   time typing.**  More than that it's
>   ++x which means about the same thing as x+=1.
>
> **Every time I see someone writing x++ in increment position I have to
>   ask does this colon understand the difference between pre-commit and
>   post-commit.  It means I have to look at every ++ in this program and
>   ask did he get this one right.  Did he get this one right?  'Cause
>   it's a little dyslexic thing which it's really hard to tell when
>   you've got them reversed.  It causes an off by one error that's only
>   off for an instant.  But that's enough to cause a bug. It's really
>   hard to debug those things.**
>
> **The argument in favor of ++ is it improves readability, which is
>   bullshit.  It does not improve readability.  It improves ambiguity. 
>   It improves confusion, which are things which are not desirable.**
>
> I was redoing some code and I saw ++x; ++x; So what's going on there? 
>   It's possible that it was a copy and paste error.  Except the code
>   seemed to be working.  More likely what had happened was someone had
>   done a ++x and then someone else noticed there's an off by one problem
>   here.  So they did it again. If the original code had said +=1 then
>   the obvious solution would be +=2.
>
> **It raises the question why do we think we need completely different
>   syntax for adding one to a variable than every other value?  How does
>   that make any sense? The answer is it does not make any sense.** 
>   There's this emotional attachment we have to bad grammar in our
>   languages that makes us feel ++ that's who I am. It's part of who I
>   am.  If you take ++ away from me what am I?  What's left? (whimpers)
>   For no cost, by adopting a more rigorous style, many classes of errors
>   can be automatically avoided.

I agree with almost all of it (especially with the key ideas I made bold) and see no point of using `++` instead of `+= 1` anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I think that loopwise, the increment and decrement operators aren't really harmful (from what I've seen) but you shouldnt use it outside of loops.